# Selecting children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML as part of a longer list.

I have code which selected the `"data-markerid"` value of the outer `<li>`. How do I access the `<div>` inside `"list-content"`?

Example: I want to access `<div class="locn-name">` inside the `<li data-markerid="0">`

Thanks!

```
<li data-markerid="0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
    <div class="list-label">1</div>
    <div class="list-details">
      <div class="list-content" id="INS0000000003">
        <div class="loc-name">Corona, Linda</div>
        <div class="loc-addr">71 Eagle Street</div> 
        <div class="loc-addr2">Brisbane, QLD 4001</div> 
        <div class="loc-phone">07 4343 9696</div>
        <div class="loc-phone">0412 563 235</div>
        <div class="loc-name">INS0000000003</div>
        <div id="loc-lat" class="cust-list-locn">-27.46818730</div>
        <div id="loc-lon" class="cust-list-locn">153.03021970</div>         
       </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
$('li[data-markerid=0] div.loc-name');
```

Read it from right to left: *"div with class "locn-name""* (`div.loc-name`) *"inside"* () *"LI of "data-markerid=0""* (`li[data-markerid=0]`).

If you have the ID in a variable, just use string concatenation:

```
$('li[data-markerid=' + id +'] ...');
```

---

More info:

- [Element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)
- [Class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)
- [Attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [Descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Comment: "Read it from right to left" == Pro Tip. In case it's not obvious that that's a CSS selector, the same is true for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
    var my_data-markerid = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-markerid');
});
```

hope this helps :-)

Comment: Oops, it was the reverse function, misunderstanding, sry. The code from Felix is the right one :-)

Comment: `my_data-markerid` is not a valid JavaScript variable.

Comment: Name it as you like, my_data_markerid or whatever, it should work and was for explaination only